# Proper way to iterate Python dictionary and build new one

Tags: python, python-3.x, dmarc

I'm trying to find a cogent way to check to see whether certain keys exist in a dictionary and use those to build a new one.

Here is my example json:

```
 "dmarc": {
    "record": "v=DMARC1; p=none; rua=mailto:dmarc.spc@test.domain; adkim=s; aspf=s",
    "valid": true,
    "location": "test.domain",
    "warnings": [
                "DMARC record at root of test.domain has no effect"
                ],
     "tags": {
            "v": {
                   "value": "DMARC1",
                   "explicit": true
                 },
            "p": {
                   "value": "none",
                   "explicit": true
                 },
            "rua": {
                   "value": [
                          {
                           "scheme": "mailto",
                           "address": "ssc.dmarc.spc@canada.ca",
                           "size_limit": null
                          }
                         ],
                   "explicit": true
                   },
            "adkim": {
                   "value": "s",
                   "explicit": true
                     },
            "aspf": {
                   "value": "s",
                   "explicit": true
                   },
            "fo": {
                   "value": [
                             "0"
                            ],
                   "explicit": false
                  },
           "pct": {
                   "value": 100,
                   "explicit": false
                  },
           "rf": {
                  "value": [
                            "afrf"
                           ],
                  "explicit": false
                 },
           "ri": {
                  "value": 86400,
                  "explicit": false
                 },
           "sp": {
                  "value": "none",
                  "explicit": false
                 }
             }
       }
 }
```

What I'm specifically looking to do, is pull `record`, `valid`, `location`, `tags-p`, `tags-sp`, and `tags-pct` in a programmatic way, instead of doing a bunch of try/excepts.  For example, to get `valid`, I do:

```
try:
    res_dict['valid'] = jsonData['valid']
except KeyError:
    res_dict['valid'] = None
```

Now, this is easy enough to loop/repeat for top level key/values, but how would I accomplish this for the nested key/values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of handling this is by taking advantage of the fact that the result of `dict.keys` can be treated as a `set`. See the following code.

```
my_keys = {'record', 'valid', 'location'} # you can add more here
new_dict = {}
available_keys = my_keys & jsonData.keys()
for key in available_keys:
    new_dict[key] = jsonData[key]
```

Above, we define the keys we are interested in within the `my_keys` set. We then get the available keys by taking the intersection of the keys in the dictionary and the keys we are interested in. This, in effect, only gets the keys that we are interested in that are also defined in the dictionary. Finally, we just iterate through the `available_keys` and build the new dictionary.

However, this does not set keys to `None` if they do not exist in the input dictionary. For that, it may be best to use the `get` method as mentioned in other answers, like so:

```
my_keys = ['record', 'valid', 'location'] # you can add more here
new_dict = {}
for key in my_keys:
    new_dict[key] = jsonData.get(key)
```

The `get` method allows us to attempt to get the value for a key in the dictionary. If that key is not defined, it returns `None`. You can also change the returned default by adding an extra argument to the `get` method like so `new_dict[key] = jsonData.get(key, "some other default value")`

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't need a `try-except` block for the same. You can check if the key exists using:

```
if jsonData.get("valid"):
    res_dict["valid"] = jsonData.get("valid")
```

The `.get("key")` method returns the value for the given `key`, if present in the dictionary. If not, then it will return None (if get() is used with only one argument).

If you want it to return something else if it doesn't find the `key` then suppose:

```
jsonData.get("valid", "invalid_something_else")
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple: instead of `dict['key']` use

- `dict.get('key', {})` for all nodes that are not leaves, and
- `dict.get('key', DEFAULT)` for leaves, where `DEFAULT` is whatever you need.

If you omit `DEFAULT` and `'key'` is absent, you get `None`. See [`the docs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get).

E.g.:

```python
jsonData.get('record', "")    # empty string if no 'record' key
jsonData.get('valid', False)  # False if no 'valid' key
jsonData.get('location')      # None if no 'location'
jsonData.get('tags', {}).get('p')  # None if no 'tags' and/or no 'p'
jsonData.get('tags', {}).get('p', {})  # {} if no 'tags' and/or no 'p'
jsonData.get('tags', {}).get('p', {}).get('explicit', False)  # and so on
```

The above presumes that you don't traverse lists (JSON arrays). If you do, you can still use

- `dict.get('key', [])`

but if you have to dive deeper from there, you will probably have to loop over list items.

Comment: Thanks for your input on this.